# Samba Server does restrict writing but not browsing or reading

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, samba, file-permissions

I made a Samba Server with 3 shares for each user and I would like to restrict access to it so only those users can access their folder. I have been browsing so much only that I got a mad headache already but none of what I found seems to resolve my problem.

My OS: Ubuntu Server

Here are my users:

1. User1 (me) : has root permissions on password
2. User2 : Doesn't have root permissions
3. User3 : Doesn't have root permissions

I specified each share in the smb.conf:

```
[share1]
path = /media/files/User1
valid users: User1
...
```

```
[share2]
path = /media/files/User2
valid users: User2
...
```

```
[share3]
path = /media/files/User3
valid users: User3
...
```

I have set permissions:

```
chown User1 /media/files/User1
chown User2 /media/files/User2
chown User3 /media/files/User3
```

Do avoid any stupid moments, I have reloaded the smb.conf file as well as restarted the smbd process:

```
smbcontrol smbd reload-config
systemctl restart smbd
```

I did a server restart and it still won't work.

Here's my problem:

**User1 (me)**: User1 can access everything, but should only access User1

**User2**: User2 can access User2 (read, browse and write) and User3 (read and browse) but not User1

**User3**: User3 can access User2 (read and browse) and User3 (read, browse and write) but not User2

What did I do wrong? Do I need a separate non-root account for me (User1)?

Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion : For the user1 share, add the commands `read list = user2, user3` and `write list = user1`, etc for the others.

Comment: @harrymc I don't think I understand it quite correctly.. I want them to be only able to browse, edit and write their own folder. Not others. User1 should only have access to read, write and browser their own as well as User2 should only be able to browse, write and read their own. Same thing with User3. Doesn't your suggestion make the other users able to read what User1 is doing in his folder?

Comment: What group owns the directories?

Comment: @Tobias: Use these clauses as you need to.

Comment: also remember, that Samba sits atop filesystem permissions on Disk, so make sure your filesystem access is set up to grant the capabilities you want to expose via Samba. Samba can further tighten security, but it cannot loosen it.

Comment: @JW0914 I don't have any groups. Only separate accounts for each user.

Comment: @Tobias What group owns the directory and subdirectories/files of `/media/files/<User1|User2|User3>`? Each Samba user must own their directories as the User, and `root` as the Group if wanting `root` to have access to each Samba user's directories. Permissions should always be applied recursively, e.g. `chown -R User1:root /media/files/User1`

Comment: use `ls -al` to show us the directories you are trying to share. we need to see the owner, ownergroup, and the permissions on those directories. Note that Samba cannot configure the permissions of the underlying directory, so your Samba configuration matter less at this point than your filesystem permissions.